# Specify listening address 0.0.0.0 for forwarded port in VSCode Remote Containers

Tags: vscode-remote

I am developing inside a docker container using the VSCode Remote Containers extension. I start a server inside the container which listens at port 3342 and would like to access the webpage using other devices in the same network.

I forward port 3342 inside the Ports tab and I am able to open the webpage in my host OS using `localhost:3342` and `127.0.0.1:3342`, but failed when using my local IP address `10.10.11.90:3342`.

I checked the listening ports in my host OS:

```
> sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:3342 | grep LISTEN
Code\x20H 4181 alvin   27u  IPv4 0x65c113c13860c1b7      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3342 (LISTEN)
```

It seems that VSCode is only listening at `127.0.0.1`.

Is there a way for me to tell VSCode to listen at `0.0.0.0` so that it accepts requests from all network interface?

---

My configuration:

- OS: macOS 10.15.7
- VSCode: 1.57.0
- VSCode Remote Containers extension: 0.183.0

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In VSCode settings, set to "All Interfaces" here:

> **Remote: Local Port Host**
>
> allInterfaces

If it's set to "localhost", devContainers forwarded ports will only listen to `127.0.0.1`.

When set to "allInterfaces", it will listen to `0.0.0.0`.

See screenshot for context:
[image]

Comment: @AlvinLeung Had the exact same problem happen to me today, it was working, then VSCode updated to 1.57.0 and it wasn't. Not sure if the setting was changed by the updated or newly added. The above fixed it for me.

Comment: This saved me from burnout

Comment: Thanks!  Solved my problem.  Even ChatGPT didn't have this answer.  StackOverflow lives on!

Comment: This solved my problem completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For VSCode: 1.69.0 on Ubuntu, the forward setting page is not available.

It is verified that we can do allinterface port forwarding by modifying the devcontainer.json by adding in the following parameters.

```
"appPort": ["8107:8107"],
```

After relaunching your container, the port forwarding can be verified in the "port" tab of the tool bar.

[image]

You can find the [official reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) of appPort parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Update to Ubuntu comment made earlier:
If you don't change the Remote: Local Port Host setting then vscode will only listen on 127.0.0.1 and not on its public ip address

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:5432 | grep LISTEN
code    76068 brent   42u  IPv4 1089447      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
```

[image: Remote: forward setting]

- Manage settings and type forward
- go to the remote extension settings
- change Remote: Local Port Host from localhost to all interfaces.
  As of vscode 1.79.2 vscode has the Remote: Local Port Host setting when running on Ubuntu 22.04 and the "appPort": ["5432:5432"] setting is not allowed in the devcontainer.json file. After the setting is changed in vscode and the container is rebuilt vscode will listen on all interfaces not just 127.0.0.1

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:5432 | grep LISTEN
code    76068 brent   42u  IPv4 1216443      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux your can also use

```
    "runArgs": [
        // Use the network stack of the host machine
        "--net=host"
    ]
```

**NOT SUPPORTED ON MAC**