# In a vscode development container, is there a way to access the docker container from a different machine on the local network?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, networking, vscode-remote, sveltekit

I have an app (sveltekit) running inside and would like to access it from other devices on my local network.

I ***can*** access it normally from the host machine on localhost:3000.

I ***want*** to access it somehow from another machine on the local network. Is this possible? [Sveltekit cli](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#command-line-interface-svelte-kit-dev) has --host flag, which outputs the following:

```
$ svelte-kit dev --host

local:   http://localhost:3000
network: http://172.17.0.3:3000
```

How do I access that network url from a different device on the local network?

```
OS: Pop OS
VSCode: 1.63.0 
Docker: Latest stable version.
```

Docker [Installed using](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) repository. Running in [rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/).

Comment: My use case: I want to see my website on my actual physical phone while I'm developing.

Comment: when you start dev server with `-host` you are already given the IP address to your `local` network which you can use to connect from your phone, if your phone is connected over same wifi router. however, you may also need to expose your `port 3000` in your OS's firewall else no one can connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify listening address 0.0.0.0 for forwarded port in VSCode Remote Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983378/specify-listening-address-0-0-0-0-for-forwarded-port-in-vscode-remote-containers)

Comment: @Chris hi, yes this is the same link I'm referring to in the accepted answer below :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that was needed was to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67997839/9689661) the following VSCode setting. By default it was set to "localhost". Setting it to "allInterfaces" grants access to other devices on the local network.

```
// settings.json

"remote.localPortHost": "allInterfaces"
```

Then, on another device connected to the same wifi network, use the following URL:

```
Format: <your-local-ip>:3000
Example: 192.168.1.105:3000
```

Note: In this scenario passing `--host` to the sveltekit cli is not required. VSCode seems to be handling that.